# Using "var" for string initialization

Tags: c#, .net

If I have a string and I initialize it to string.Empty, then

```
var mystring=string.Empty;
```

or

```
string mystring = string.Empty;
```

Which of the above two should be better wrt performance or any other considerations?

Comment: [var (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)

Comment: It is the same thing, so no difference

Comment: `var` is a *compile*-time construct. By the time the code is running, they've become the same code. So there are no performance considerations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var` is an *implicit type*. It aliases any type in the C# programming language. The aliased type is determined by the C# compiler.

The `var` keyword has equivalent performance. **It does not affect runtime behavior.**

Your both codes generate same IL code;

```
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldsfld     string [mscorlib]System.String::Empty
IL_0006:  stloc.0
IL_0007:  ret
```

Answer (score 0):

They both compile to the same IL code, so there is no performance difference during code execution.

However, the second one is more readable, and I would go that way.

Comment: Respectfully, my style is to always use `var` when I can. It I fine that we disagree, but to infer that one is better than the other on any basis than personal style is presumptious.

Comment: I think using `var` while you're initializing simple types, like `int`, `double` or `string` should be avoided, but as you said I's just an opinion.

Comment: I'm a huge `var` fan too: I don't want to care about types unless I must, being that the compiler is smart enough to allow me to.

Comment: One point: In the case of loop indices the use of `var` over `int` or `long` is explicitly recommended by MSDN guidelines